# Scala and Akka : ActorSystem class not found even with the config.jar

Tags: android, scala, akka

I'm working on an Android application written in Scala in which I also use the Akka library. As I'm quite a beginner, I'm using Eclipse and I let it manage the dependencies. Currently, I have in my build path:

- the Scala library 2.10.2
- the Android libraries
- akka-actor_2.10-2.2.1.jar
- config-1.0.0.jar

But sadly, when I try to instantiate this :

```
val system = ActorSystem("mySystem")
```

I'm meeting this kind of error :

```
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490):    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:93)
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490):    at com.example.sudokuscala.Game.<init>(Game.scala:230)
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-05 17:56:47.071: E/AndroidRuntime(24490):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If you could help me, that will be great ! Thanks in advance !

Comment: I would suggest using a dependency management tool like Maven, Gradle or sbt. It will make managing dependencies so much easier and can resolve the dependencies of your dependencies. You wirte you let Eclipse manage your dependencies, how exactly do you do that? AFAIK Eclipse will only use libs you have manually added to the classpath. Maven and Gradle have a nice Eclipse integration, so you can still do everything from Eclipse, but do not have to manually download any dependencies.

Comment: In addition you will probably have to make sure that the translation to Dalvik keeps all the needed classes and methods, I have never tried that myself, though. You can find some examples by googling for "akka proguard".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a runtime exception that means you have to correct your launch configuration. Go to Eclipse Run Configuration -> Classpath tab then add config-1.0.0.jar as a dependency. According to migration guide Akka 2.10 uses config-1.0.0.jar this must fix this issue. Finally as @pushy mentioned in the comment it's always better to use Maven/Ivy/SBT for dependency management in development.

Comment: Ok guys thanks for your answers ! Actually, I've finally decided to use SBT. It took me some time to get how to use it, but now everything is fine and my application is even lighter (from 4MB with Eclipse to 1MB now) !!! Thanks again